# Updating database tables from the front end

Tags: jquery, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this. I currently have Flask with PyMySQL and SQLAlchemy installed to handle the back end database connection. I've linked the connection in the config file and have been using it fine. The front end uses Angular CLI with bootstrap, but has other things installed such as JQUERY, Popper, and primeng.

The problem is that I need to access the database and update/delete/insert data from a form on the front end. So a user could type in a text box a query and my database will run it. I know how to get data from the back end and bring it to show on the front end, but I can't figure out how to go the other way around.

With this, if there is an error message on the update/delete/insert such as violating a foreign key policy, that message needs to be shown back to the front end.

Any help with this would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can submit form with AJAX. After user clicks submit button on your form, you collect all the data from `input`s in a form and send it like so (using JQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUpUser',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And on the flask side:

```
@app.route('/signUpUser', methods=['POST'])
def signUpUser():
    user =  request.form['username']
    password = request.form['password']
    # Use form data for CRUD in your database
```